# Docker run, no space left on device

Tags: linux, docker, centos7

```
[root@host ~]# docker run 9e7de9390856

Timestamp: 2015-06-15 22:20:58.8367035 +1000 AEST
Code: System error

Message: [/usr/bin/tar -xf /var/lib/docker/tmp/cde0f3a199597ac2e18e7efc7744c84a6c134adef31fb88b6982a8732f45efa5090033894/_tmp.tar -C /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/cde0f3a199597ac2e18e7efc7744c84a6c134adef31fb88b6982a8732f45efa5/rootfs/tmp .] failed: /usr/bin/tar: ./was/fixPack/7.0.0-WS-WASSDK-LinuxX64-FP0000027.pak: Wrote only 4608 of 10240 bytes
/usr/bin/tar: ./was/fixPack/wasFixPackInstallResponseFile: Cannot write: No space left on device
.
.
Cannot write: No spaFATA[0141] Error response from daemon: : exit status 2
```

df -h:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda2      6.0G  3.2G  2.9G  52% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.8G   17M  1.8G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdb1       99G   28G   67G  30% /var/lib/docker
```

docker info:

```
Containers: 2
Images: 34
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-202:17-2621441-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 15.89 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 76.3 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 10.27 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.137 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.93-RHEL7 (2015-01-28)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.1 (Maipo)
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.452 GiB
Name: ip-10-100-128-182.localdomain
ID: 4ZZZ:BSQD:GBKL:4Y3N:J6BL:47QE:3HMQ:GLMY:FPUK:CEPM:3EBP:ZU7G
Debug mode (server): true
Debug mode (client): false
Fds: 13
Goroutines: 18
System Time: Mon Jun 15 22:48:24 AEST 2015
EventsListeners: 0
Init SHA1: 836be3a369bfc6bd4cbd3ade1eedbafcc1ea05d0
Init Path: /usr/libexec/docker/dockerinit
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
```

uname -a:
Linux ip-10-100-128-182.localdomain 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 29 18:37:38 EST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Anyone can help me?
Not sure this information is enough. But tried couple of solutions, nothing worked.

docker version:
Client version: 1.6.0
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 8aae715/1.6.0
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.6.0
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 8aae715/1.6.0
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64

```
[root@host ~]# service docker status -l
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  -l docker.service
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2015-06-16 00:31:46 AEST; 2min 2s ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 3306 (docker)
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─3306 /usr/bin/docker -d --storage-opt dm.basesize=30G --storage-opt dm.loopmetadatasize=4G
```

Comment: can you post `docker ps -a` , maybe you still have many "dead" containers

Comment: nope, i dont have any containers.. removed everything.

Comment: post `ls -alrt /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/`

Comment: What is image `9e7de9390856`? How big is it?

Comment: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/ contains around some 30-40  empty directories

Comment: 9e7de9390856 size is 14GB

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're trying to start a container from a 14GB image.

A Docker container, when using the `devicemapper` storage driver, only has 10GB of space available by default.  You appear to be using the `devicemapper` driver, so this is probably the source of your problem.

[This article](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/01/29/docker-device-mapper-resize/) discusses in detail the process you need to use to increase the amount of space available for container filesystems.

Filesystem-based drivers (like the `overlay` driver) to not have this same limitation (but they may of course suffer from other limitations).

Comment: i have changed to 3.10.5-12.1.x86_64 aufs driver, but still getting errors!

Comment: yes the same errors, i can create container with 1gb image.